# Cannot access nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Introduction:

I am trying to access nested dictionary element in python, which looks like this:

`{'CA':{'1':'3','2':'3','3':'3'},'IL': {'1':'31','2':'45','3':'23'},...}`

Firstly I read from Excel file, where I get names of states and then assign a dictionary to each state. This is how I do it:

```
xls_file = pd.ExcelFile('D:/CollegeScorecardDataDictionary-08-18-2016.xlsx')
dfEx = xls_file.parse('Church')  # Parse Church sheet
for (i, item) in enumerate(stateName):
     if stateChurchDict.get(item)<>None:
            continue 
     else:
            stateChurchDict[item] = dict
```

Once loop is iterated, I have something like this:

`{'CA':<type dict>,'IL': <type dict>,'AL': <type dict>...}`

In each state there are lots of churches which can be categorized in either `'1', '2' or '3'` 
This is where I got the numbers in the nested dictionaries.

My problem is I want to refer to a nested dictionary of certain state like

`stateChurchDict['AL']['3']`

and get the number of churches under category '3' in a certain state. However, firstly I have to check if it empty or not, if it is empty the value has to be added. Thus, I came up with this:

```
for (i, item) in enumerate(stateName):
            if stateChurchDict[stateName[i-1]]['3'] <> None:
                stateChurchDict.update({stateChurchDict[stateName[i-1]]['3']: stateChurchDict[stateName[i-1]]['3'] + 1})
            else:
                stateChurchDict[stateName[i-1]]['3'] = 1
```

BUT, this `stateChurchDict[stateName[i-1]]['3']` cannot access the nested dictionary, however `stateName[i-1] == 'AL'` and it calls the element like `stateChurchDict['AL']['3']` and still nothing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am posting the whole stuff for a better explanation:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
def IsNumeric(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return x
    except:
        return 0
xls_file = pd.ExcelFile('D:/CollegeScorecardDataDictionary-08-18-2016.xlsx')
dfEx = xls_file.parse('Church')  # Parse data_dictionary sheet
dfCsv = pd.read_csv('D:/MERGED2014_15_PP.csv', low_memory=False)
churchCode = dfEx.Code  # Label column
churchName = dfEx.ChurchName  # Value column
churchCategory = dfEx.Category  # Church category
relafil = dfCsv.RELAFFIL  # Religious Id in CSV
stateName = dfCsv.STABBR  # Name of state
churchList = {}  # Create dictionary to store churches
stateChurchDict = defaultdict(Counter)  # Create dictionary to store churches by state
stateChurchTemp = {} #Sepate dictionary for churches by state
# Put values into dictionary
for (i, v) in enumerate(churchCode):
    churchList[v] = churchCategory[i] #Assigns a category to each church in state

for (i, item) in enumerate(stateName): #Create a dictionary as a value to each state in the stateChurchList dictionary
    if item <> None:
        if stateChurchDict.get(item) <> None:
            continue
        else:
            stateChurchDict[item] = {}

for (i, item) in enumerate(stateName): #Iterate through states and count the number of churches by categories. Once the state name is changed, the number needs to be transferred from stateChurchTemp to stateChurchDict
    if IsNumeric(relafil[i]) <> 0:
        if i >= 1 and item <> stateName[i - 1]:
            if stateChurchDict[stateName[i - 1]][3] <> None:
                stateChurchDict.update({stateChurchDict[stateName[i - 1]][3]: stateChurchDict[stateName[i - 1]][
                                                                                    3] + IsNumeric(
                    stateChurchTemp[3])})
            else:
                stateChurchDict[stateName[i - 1]][3] = IsNumeric(stateChurchTemp[3])
            if stateChurchDict[stateName[i - 1]][2] <> None:
                stateChurchDict.update({stateChurchDict[stateName[i - 1]][2]: stateChurchDict[stateName[i - 1]][
                                                                                    2] + IsNumeric(
                    stateChurchTemp[2])})
            else:
                stateChurchDict[stateName[i - 1]][2] = IsNumeric(stateChurchTemp[2])
            if stateChurchDict[stateName[i - 1]][1] <> None:
                stateChurchDict.update({stateChurchDict[stateName[i - 1]][1]: stateChurchDict[stateName[i - 1]][
                                                                                    1] + IsNumeric(
                    stateChurchTemp[1])})
            else:
                stateChurchDict[stateName[i - 1]][1] = IsNumeric(stateChurchTemp[1])
        if churchList.get(relafil[i]) <> None and stateChurchTemp.get(churchList.get(relafil[i])) <> None:
            stateChurchTemp.update({churchList.get(relafil[i]): stateChurchTemp.get(churchList.get(relafil[i])) + 1})
        else:
            stateChurchTemp[churchList.get(relafil[i])] = 1
print stateChurchDict
```

Comment: Where did you see `<>`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham A deprecated form of `!=`. Still works in Py2

Comment: '<type dict>' is a new dictionary, which is not yet populated with data.

Comment: Use `'3' in stateChurchDict[stateName[i-1]` to check if '3' is present in the dict or not.

Comment: @RustamUmarov, assign it as `stateChurchDict[item] = {}`, you may find a `collections.defaultdict ` is your friend here. Also your enumerate is redundantr and you could just create the dict as `{item:{} for item in stateName }`

Comment: ['3'] is not there yet, therefore I am checking it. If `stateChurchDict[stateName[i-1]]['3']` gives me None, which means it does not exist, then I have to create it and assign value = 1

Comment: @PadraicCunningham can you please explain this specifically?

Comment: @Rustam,  `d = defauldict(defaultdict)`, you also don't use update to add a single key/value pair

Comment: @PadraicCunningham this `stateChurchDict[item] = {}` absolutely looks better, but still, if '3' does not exist, then it gives me a key error.

Comment: @RustamUmarov, that is where the defaultdict comes in, add a small sample of input and expected output.

Comment: I have never used `defaultdict` in my practice in python, since I am dealing with it not for a long time. Can you please apply `defaultdict` to my case?

Comment: `<>` is deprecated and should be removed. Using it is a sign of poor coding practices and poor maintainability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the nested dictionary, you trying to update the main one. Please change this line:

```
stateChurchDict.update({stateChurchDict[stateName[i - 1]][2]: stateChurchDict[stateName[i - 1]][2] + IsNumeric(stateChurchTemp[2])})
```

with this:

```
stateChurchDict.get(statename[i-1]).update({3: stateChurchDict[stateName[i - 1]][3] + IsNumeric(stateChurchTemp[3])})
```

Answer (score 1):

`stateChurchDict` should probably not have been a *vanilla* dictionary in the first place.

A [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) passed to a [`collections.defauldict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is the right direction here:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict, Counter
>>> d = defaultdict(Counter) # or defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
>>> d['AL']['3']
0
```

With this, default count values are generated on the fly for keys nested up to two levels, and your code reduces to:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

stateChurchDict = defaultdict(Counter)
for i, item in enumerate(stateName):
    stateChurchDict[stateName[i-1]]['3'] += 1
```

Comment: I bet you're missing something, as that shouldn't raise a `KeyError`. How did you implement this?

Comment: Do you want to see the whole stuff?

Comment: You have problems with your code e.g. `stateChurchDict[item] = {}` will replace the `Counter` object with a normal dictionary. That initial for loop will no longer be needed. And the dictionary updates also. You should probably give a look to the links for `defaultdict` and `Counter`

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this is how I came to answer. Simply, I created another dictionary `internalDict`, which stores nested dictionary's values.

Instead of calling `stateChurchDict[stateName[i-1][3]]` I tried `internalDict = stateChurchDict[stateName[i-1]]`, and afterwards worked only with `internalDict`. As a result, was calling `stateChurchDict[stateName[i-1][3]]` like `internalDict[3]`.